# redirect from javascript function is not working

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have one js file in which there is one function

```
function deleterec(delid)    
{    
 if(confirm('Are you sure you want to "'+jQuery("#action").attr('value')+'" the selected record(s)?'))    
 {
    document.location.href = siteroot+"/admin/products/delete_store.php?delid="+delid;
 } 
 else
 {
    return false;
 }
```

In which delid are comma seperated id passed to function.
But in confirmation it does redirect to delete_store.php file in which i write this code

```
if($_GET['delid']!="")    
{       
    mysql_query("delete from store where id in (".$_GET['delid'].")");    
    $_SESSION['msg'] = "<span class='success'>Record deleted successfully</span>";      
}
```

But it doesn't work, I think from js function it does not redirect to delete_store.php.

Comment: Don't use a GET request to delete things. GET requests are supposed to be nice, safe, bookmarkable, robot friendly things. Use POST. Don't set location.href, submit a form, and have the submit event handler `return confirm(...)`.

Comment: Hello SQL injection.  Sanitise your `$_GET['delid']`.

Comment: explain in detail in my code please....

Comment: How is `deleterec` called? And where is `siteroot` and what value is it?

Comment: deleterec() is called on submit button, siteroot is a main url path to that file. siteroot is not the problem, it works

Answer (score 0):

The `document.location` can be read-only in some browsers. That can be the problem. Try using `window.location` instead.